# How to convert a decimal to binary using built-in method from library in java?

Tags: java, binary, hex, decimal

How can i convert a decimal into binary?
Is there any built in method which i can use to convert decimal into binary?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want the binary representation of an integer number. You could use [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) -

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(255));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1));
```

Output is (the expected)

```
0
11111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

If my assumption is incorrect and you want the hex representation you can always use [`Integer.toHexString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(255));
```

Which will get

```
ff
```

Finally, there's [`Integer.toOctalString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString%28int%29) if you need that. And, to reverse these operations there is [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) where the second argument is the *radix*.

Comment: This converts a binary integer, not a decimal number.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this method Integer.toBinaryString() it's built-in in java

Comment: This converts a binary integer, not a decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

The java.lang package provides the functionality to convert  a decimal number into a binary number. The method toBinaryString() comes in handy for such purpose. Bellow is the code:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class DecimalToBinary{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.println("Enter the decimal value:");
  String hex = bf.readLine();
  int i = Integer.parseInt(hex);  
  String by = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
  System.out.println("Binary: " + by);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hex is not decimal.