# Java binary conjunction

Tags: java, binary

Reading about binary operations in Java i'm stack of next example :

```
10111011 & 00001000 = 00001000
```

00001000 is a 8 in [decimal represenation](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html)

but when i try to execute the following code :

```
    System.out.println("10111011 & 00001000 = " + (0b10111011 & 0b00001000));
    System.out.println("10111011 & 00001000 = " + Integer.toString(0b10111011 & 0b00001000, 2));
```

i getting output :

```
10111011 & 00001000 = 8 // right!
10111011 & 00001000 = 1000 // not a 00001000!
```

So i have 2 questions :

<strike>**1) Why when i make conjunction operations i have invalid result?**</strike>(My mistake)
**2) Why in output i have only part visible of bits? How i can see all of bits count? Why Integer.toString(value,radix) doesn't return full record as 00001000?**

## Can be deleted. Problem solved. My mistake

Comment: 1. Why were you expecting `4`? 2. Why would it show more bits than necessary; how many zeroes would you have liked?!

Comment: Anything without the `4` bit set for a bitwise and sure isn't going to have it set in the result. Because leading zeros aren't significant? You probably want to format it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 1) i added a link of online converter. 2) Just for fun. I use a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406432/converting-an-int-to-a-binary-string-representation-in-java to help of output.

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The result is correct 00001000 in binary = 8 in decimal. Why were you expecting 4? Even your question mentions the correct answer.

2) The toString method for int does not zero pad values.

Comment: how i can specify of output?

Comment: @SergeyShustikov See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

You'd generally use String.Format(...) in this case. My original answer was slightly inaccurate as it suggested you could pass a format string to the toString method.