# Efficient or an alternative way to store data in a key / value style in Java

Tags: java, key-value, treemap

I wrote a program that takes a *String* and gives it's *binary* representation ( for example the letter "a" to 01000001) and emit a tone with frequency that denotes that *binary* representation. The frequency to be used in matching with the given binary representation relies on a *TreeMap*.

The second program listens for the tones, does some fft and other calculations to determine which frequency it was. Now after finding the corresponding frequency it has to translate it back to binary (01000001) to be formatted to ASCII and therefore re-construct the String. My problem is, the *binary* combinations and their matching frequencies are hard coded in a *TreeMap* used by both programs. This means 512 pairs had to be written in the source file that looks a little something like

```
ToneMap() {
        // binary representation and the matching frequency
        frequency.put("00000000", 400);

        frequency.put("00000001", 433);

        frequency.put("00000010", 466);

        frequency.put("00000011", 499);

        frequency.put("00000100", 532);

        frequency.put("00000101", 565);

        frequency.put("00000110", 598);

        frequency.put("00000111", 631);

        frequency.put("00001000", 664);

        frequency.put("00001001", 697);

        frequency.put("00001010", 730);

        frequency.put("00001011", 763);

        // followed by a lot more
```

This is obviously very wrong and inefficient. What are the alternatives to storing / generating the byte / frequency pairs on both programs without having to rely on a hard coded TreeMap.

Comment: How did you arrive at those values in the first place? Looks like they're evenly spaced - can you just generate them in a loop?

Comment: 400+33*x where x is your input number? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406432/converting-an-int-to-a-binary-string-representation-in-java for converting "binary strings" <-> numbers

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I took two ranges, the lower bound being 400hz and upper bound being around 9000hz, then divided 256 different combinations into them so roughly 33hz difference between each entry.

Comment: @jontro More or less.

Comment: Is there some sort of a mathematical relation I can use on both sides to calculate the frequency and the byte combination? Say I recive 664hz. I know the two ranges (upper and lower bound), that way I can find the index at which 664hz resides. After knowing the index, I can again find which byte combination that index falls ( between 00000000 - 11111111)?

Comment: @aval `Integer.toBinaryString( (664-400)/33)` ?

Comment: @jontro Perfect and so simple, shaking my head here. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @jontro, see comment.

Since the starting range and ending range are known ( 400hz and 9000hz). The retrieved frequency can be used with the range to find the index of that frequency and thus the byte representation

```
     // 33 is difference between adjacent frequencies, 
     // the value of index is 8 which translates to 1000 using
     Integer.toBinaryString( (664-400)/33) 

     //and from the original ToneMap, shows the value obtained from the above code is correct
     frequency.put("00001000", 664);
```