# Accessing digits of a binary number

Tags: java

Let's say i have a binary number initialized like this:

```
   int y=0b110101;
```

How could i convert 110101 to a String?
I would like this:

```
String str1 = Integer.toString(y); 

System.out.println(str1);
```

to give result 110101 or 0b110101 and not 53.

Comment: `String str1 = Integer.toBinaryString(y);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an int to a binary string representation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406432/converting-an-int-to-a-binary-string-representation-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.toBinaryString(y)` would give you `110101` in your case and you can prepend the `0b` to the result if you'd like that.