# Int cannot be converted to binary string

Tags: java, string, int

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String a = "10";
    String b = "11";

    int a0 = Integer.parseInt(a, 2);
    int b1 = Integer.parseInt(b, 2);

    int product = a0 * b1;
    Integer.toString(product);
    int result = Integer.parseInt(product);
    System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

I've tried all the methods I've seen in stackoverflow and none of them work in my case. I can convert the binary to base10, but can't convert it back.

Comment: The error is ocurring on which line? Also... Do you really need to parseInt product?

Comment: like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406432/converting-an-int-to-a-binary-string-representation-in-java

Comment: Printed binary is simply a visual representation of a number like decimal, or hex.  But the default when printing integers is to print them in the decimal representation.  If you want a binary string, just do `String result = Integer.toBinaryString(product);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, everything is `binary`.  But visually, binary is just one representation for human consumption.  Other primary ones are `octal`, `decimal`, or `hex`. But the `default` when printing integers is to print them in the `decimal representation`. If you want a binary string, just do:

```
    String a = "10";
    String b = "11";

    int a0 = Integer.parseInt(a, 2);
    int b1 = Integer.parseInt(b, 2);

    int product = a0 * b1;
    String result = Integer.toBinaryString(product);
    System.out.print(result);
```

Prints

```
110
```

Also note that you can assign ints a value in binary representation.

```
int a = 0b11;
int b = 0b10;
```